# I Can't control relay using Wemos D1 mini

Tags: c, arduino

Im trying control relay using wemos D1 mini.

I was try control th relay using wemos D1 mini i connect D1 pin to IN pin, GND to GND and 5V pin to VCC pin [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bgrn.jpg) but doesn't work.
Here is my code :

```
 int relaypin = D1;
 void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     pinMode(relaypin, OUTPUT); // Make LED pin D7 an output pin
     pinMode(relaypin, LOW);
     pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
 }
 void loop() {
      digitalWrite(relaypin, LOW); // LED off
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      Serial.println("LED On");
      delay(3000); // Wait 3 seconds
      digitalWrite(relaypin, HIGH); // LED on
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      Serial.println("LED Off");
      delay(1000); // Wait 1 second
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be the reasons:

- The Wemos D1 Mini operates on **3.3V**. So, the input signal voltage to the relay board might not be sufficient. The optocoupler on the relay board requires a **typical voltage of 1.2V** to trigger the output circuit. But in your circuit, even at a HIGH output from the Wemos, the **voltage at the optocoupler is 1.7V**. So, your relay is latched at the same state *(MOST PROBABLE)*
- The 5V supply current might not be sufficient to operate the relay

How to solve these..?

- You need a voltage level converter to convert the 3.3V signals from the Wemos to 5V for the relay board
- Use a supply rated at higher currents

Also, in your code:
In `setup()` you have defined `pinMode(relaypin,LOW)` which I guess should have been `digitalWrite(relaypin,LOW)`

Answer (score 2):

use  `pinMode(relaypin, OUTPUT_OPEN_DRAIN);` instead `pinMode(relaypin, OUTPUT);`

And you win like a champion!

## Explanation

Changing the pin mode from *OUTPUT* to *OUTPUT_OPEN_DRAIN* works when you have a relay that is "Low Level Triggered" instead of "High-Level Triggered". The difference is subtle but significant.

**High Level Triggered:** The relay activates when there is a positive voltage on the com-pin. Because of this, the expected OUTPUT mode works.

**Low Level Triggered:** The relay only activates when you connect the com-pin directly to ground. There is no need for a high signal at all. Why does this matter? Even though the OUTPUT pin-mode effectively sets the pin to 3.3v or 0v, the 0v isn't actually connecting directly to ground, hence it doesn't trigger the relay. However, if you change the pin mode to OUTPUT_OPEN_DRAIN it appears to change the pin behavior so it will connect to ground(drain).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! @OdairBonin, Please elaborate on your answer and explain why you mentioned that particular line of code.

Comment: It's worked with D1 pin, but i cant understund why...

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `setup()` function. After declaring the relaypin as `OUTPUT` (which is 0x01) you immediately declared it as `LOW` (which is 0x00) which equals `INPUT`.

I guess you were meant to write: `digitalWrite(relaypin, LOW)` instead.

(You can see the defines in `./hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h`)

Comment: Like this?

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(relaypin, OUTPUT); // Make LED pin D7 an output pin
digitalWrite(relaypin, LOW);
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}